# Does C have a CPAN-like system?

Tags: c

Does C have an online code/lib sharing system,
like CPAN for Perl, pip for python, gem for ruby?

If not, Does C for GNU/Linux have one?

Thanks!

Comment: Nope, it does not. Packet managers @PierreEmmanuelLallemant is not C code sharing.

Comment: What you want is a packet manager. Under ubuntu, it is generally apt-get. There are several projects like https://conan.io/ , clib, ... but they are not used by a large community so you have to consider if you really need them. Furthermore, it doesn't make sens to install locally C packages in your project, because your whole computer will not have access to it. You will just end with enormous binary files, due to assimilation of static libraries into your executable.

Comment: @tilz0R He asks for code OR "lib" sharing system. And some packet managers provide code (under gentoo for example)

Comment: Study some [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) written in C (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/), [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) and in most [Linux distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution)....)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

In GNU/Linux, the C language is basically "the system language"; the kernel and many important parts of the operating system are written in it. Therefore, the system package manager is used to manage C dependencies.

Look for packages named `lib*-dev`, where the `*` is the actual name of the package.

For instance there's [`lib32readline-dev`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/lib32readline-dev) which is the development version of the `readline` library.

Comment: Thanks @unwind. May I ask you another question? I've learned C in college and I know some C syntax, algorithm and data structure. If I want to learn industry C in deep, is there any recommended source code to start with, or a recommended path? I want to know how C is and should be used in computer industry, just like I learn Java from some of the libraries/shared source code.

Comment: @cmal That kind of question is a bit off-topic, I recommend simply googling it. Also of course there's a huge amount of C code available to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Not an official one. But **clibs** looks promising and it seems to be quite popular:

https://github.com/clibs/clib